# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/protocol' on import webdriverio

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am writing atm some mocha tests after this guide:  https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html

My test looks just like this:

```
import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
var client = require('webdriverio').remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        platformName: 'iOS',
        app: 'net.company.SafariLauncher',
        udid: '123123123123abc',
        deviceName: 'iPhone',
    }
});

//i can also replace the upper code by:
//import webdriverio from 'webdriverio';
// or 
//const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
//but the error stays the same

describe('my module', function (done) {
  it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
     assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
   });
});
```

The error is as in the title:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/protocol'
```

I run my tests as described in the guide mentioned above:

```
meteor test --driver-package=practicalmeteor:mocha
```

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention i had this error on npm install webdriverio:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY mocha@3.5.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@15.4.2
├── webdriverio@4.8.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc
```

Since i could run mocha tests with the wdio testrunner i ignored the message. I think it is not the problem of the error but still maybe important information.

Comment: Shouldn't you run it like `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`?

Comment: ofc, fixed typo

Comment: `=` is not needed there as well

Comment: true, but i followed this guide https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html

Comment: That guide doesn't have `=` also, if that's what you mean.

Comment: true, i got it from https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha but i also run atm without the `=`

Comment: Could you check, is there indeed such file/folder? Perhaps, reinstall `webdriverio` npm package? Btw, why do you use `webdriverio` if you're starting to write meteor tests?

Comment: folder exists, and i also (re)installed the webdriver package with `npm install`and `meteor npm install`

Comment: can it be a problem that i installed practicalmeteor with `meteor add`?

Comment: No, that's correct way to install it. The problem itself seems like in `webdriverio` npm package.

Comment: Funny thing is the webdriverio dev told me it's an issue of meteor... (which i doubt)

Comment: @Styx see my update in the question

Comment: Could you try to remove `node_modules` in your app folder and reinstall them with `meteor npm i` command?

Comment: tried it, also complete rebuild / reinstall from scratch but run into the same error again

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because while importing webdriver for first time and installing packages, installation of edgeDriver failed with response code 404 and following error message is displayed:

```
Error in "getDownloadStream". Could not download https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/96.0.1054.29/edgedriver_mac64.zip
See more details below:
404 https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/96.0.1054.29/edgedriver_mac64.zip
Response code 404 (Not Found)

Ended WebDriver sessions gracefully after a SIGINT signal was received!
```

During `$npm run test` I was getting following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod /Users/{user}/webdriverio/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromiumedgedriver/latest-x64/msedgedriver
```

Hence I fixed it by following steps:

- Navigate to
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
  and click any version to download with x64 (in mycase it was x64)
- Rename the downloaded binary to `msedgedriver.exe`
- Copy`msedgedriver.exe` and paste it in `/Users/{user}/webdriverio/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromiumedgedriver/latest-x64/msedgedriver` (This is the path where ENOENT error was appearing as file was not found)
- Unzip `msedgedriver.exe` and folder will be created there with name
  `msedgedriver`
- Execute your command now.